# Why is network latency becomes too long when edit in the sshfs mounted files

Tags: buffers, performance, ssh

I mounted the remote server directory to my local machine mount point with sshfs. Thus I could use my local vim to edit my code, it is much faster than editing with the vim installed to the remote server. However, the saving process and switching between buffers becomes very slow. Each time I run `:w`, it will cost me around 20s to accomplish the saving process, and it is also very slow when I run `ctrl + w + l` or `<leader>+f` to switch between the split buffers or other opened buffers. The network is sort of slow but I am sure it is not so slow when I use `rsync` to transmit files. What is the cause of this and how could I fix it please?

Comment: Coin, in general this doesn't look like Vims fault, but there are a few settings that might influence the write performance. Could you test the following: 1) Create the directory `/tmp/vimbackup` 2) in Vim do `set backupdir=/tmp/vimbackup//` (trailing slashes are needed) 3) edit and save a file from sshfs. How is the write performance now?

Comment: I am not sure whether my operation is correct. But I checkout the default backupdir by running `:set backupdir?` and see the result of `backupdir=.,~/tmp,~/`. So I checked the current directory by running `ls -a`, but I saw no relevant files created. Also after creating `/tmp/vimbackup` and running `:set backupdir=/tmp/vimbackup`, I saw the result of `:set backupdir?` because `/tmp/vimbackup`. Then I edited the file and run `:w`. I saw no result of the command `ls -a /tmp/vimbackup`. Is my configuration not approperiate?

Comment: What Vim version do you have?

Comment: By running `vim --version` the first lines are like this: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May  2 2019 14:08:08)
Included patches: 1-1244
Compiled by coin@Arch-Dell
`

Comment: @Ralf I have made it work, and I saw backup files generated in the `/tmp/vimbackup`, but I observed no speed improvement. It is still slow when I switch between buffers or splits or save my changes. Do you have other suggestions please?

Comment: Try disabling `swapsync` and `fsync` options. Should make writing a lot faster for network attached files. However I wouldn't recommend to disable those in general

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hi, Would you please explain a bit why it is not recommended to disable these two options ?

Comment: please read the help for those options.